# Error select con c:forEach no muestra datos correctamente

Tags: html, mysql, jsp, select

Hola buen día llevo todo el día lidiando con este pedazo de código y por más que le busco no encuentro el error, básicamente lo que tiene que hacer el código es que de un select previo muestre únicamente los campos relacionados en el siguiente, el problema es que al momento de desplegar el select solo aparece el último registro relacionado repetido el mismo número de veces que los registros que existen. Adjunto el código donde este posiblemente el problema.

```
protected void SelectNegocio(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String ruta)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession sesion_actual = request.getSession(true);
    int idActualiza = (Integer)sesion_actual.getAttribute("CorporativoId");
    try {
        request.setAttribute("baseNeg", neDAO.LlenarPorIDCorporativo(idActualiza));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dis = request.getRequestDispatcher(ruta);
    dis.forward(request, response);
}
```

```
public ArrayList<Negocio> LlenarPorIDCorporativo(int id) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Negocio> lista = new ArrayList<Negocio>();
        Negocio n = new Negocio();
        try {
            this.Conectar();
            String Query = "select *from negocio where IdCorporativo = ? ";
            PreparedStatement smt = this.getCnx().prepareStatement(Query);
            smt.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rt = smt.executeQuery();
            while (rt.next()) {
                Corporativo c = new Corporativo();
                Sector s = new Sector();
                n.setId_negocio(rt.getInt("Id"));
                c.setCorporativo(rt.getString("Name"));
                s.setSector(rt.getString("Name"));
                n.setVentas(rt.getInt("Ventas"));
                n.setNegocio(rt.getString("Name"));
                n.setEmpleados(rt.getInt("Empleados"));
                n.setComentario(rt.getString("Comentario"));
                n.setSegmentos(rt.getString("Segmentos"));
                n.setCorporativo(c);
                n.setSector(s);
                lista.add(n);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error  " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            this.Desconectar();
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

```
<select name="cmbNegocio">
    <c:forEach items="${baseNeg}" var='a'>

        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${a.corporativo.id_corporativo}.Equals<%=CorporativoId %>">
                 <option value="${a.id_negocio}" selected="">${a.id_negocio}</option>
            </c:when>

            <c:otherwise>
                <option value="${a.id_negocio}">${a.id_negocio}</option>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>

    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisando el código me di cuenta que el problema era que estaba dejando el Negocio n = new Negocio(); fuera del while. Así quedaría el código por si a alguien le llega a servir en algún momento.

```
public ArrayList<Negocio> LlenarPorIDCorporativo(int id) throws Exception {

    ArrayList<Negocio> lista = new ArrayList<Negocio>();
    
    try {
        this.Conectar();
        String Query = "select *from negocio where IdCorporativo = ? ";
        PreparedStatement smt = this.getCnx().prepareStatement(Query);
        smt.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rt = smt.executeQuery();
        while (rt.next()) {
            Negocio n = new Negocio();
            Corporativo c = new Corporativo();
            Sector s = new Sector();
            n.setId_negocio(rt.getInt("Id"));
            c.setCorporativo(rt.getString("Name"));
            s.setSector(rt.getString("Name"));
            n.setVentas(rt.getInt("Ventas"));
            n.setNegocio(rt.getString("Name"));
            n.setEmpleados(rt.getInt("Empleados"));
            n.setComentario(rt.getString("Comentario"));
            n.setSegmentos(rt.getString("Segmentos"));
            n.setCorporativo(c);
            n.setSector(s);
            if(lista.contains(n))
            {
                rt.previous();
            }else
            {
             lista.add(n);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error  " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        this.Desconectar();
    }
    return lista;
}
```